# Strange behavior for overloaded I/O operator in class

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I wrote a small music program on Windows for fun. I found the part of code going wrong. This is the minimized code (MCVE) for reproducing the problem:

```
#include <iostream>
using std::istream;
using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr; // Debug output goes to stderr
using std::endl;

class Key {
    public:
    typedef signed char Pitch, Octave; // -128 to 127
    typedef signed long Absolute; // -2147M to 2147M
    Pitch p;
    Octave o;

    public:
    Key(const Pitch& _p, const Octave& _o) :
        p(_p), o(_o) {}
    Key(void) : Key(Pitch(0), Octave(0)) {};
    Absolute abs(void) const {
        return 12L * Absolute(o) + Absolute(p);
    }
    friend istream& operator>> (istream&, Key&);
};

istream& operator>> (istream& is, Key& k){
    return (is >> k.p >> k.o);
}
```

And here's the running part:

```
Key k;
cin >> k;
cout << k.abs() << endl;
```

Given the input `0 0`, the output is supposed to be `0`, but the actual output is ridiculously big (`624`). I tried this

```
cerr << k.p << k.o << endl;
```

And the output is `00` (no space between, see code), as expected.

Comment: @StoryTeller It's my fault. I shut down my PC after coding and I (as usual) surf the web on my 5.5" Android phone, including SO. I re-wrote the code by memory so new typos may occur in questions and answers.

Comment: Alright. Given the code is correct now, not a bad question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`is >> k.p` has special behaviour because `k.p` has character type.  The input `0` will generate the character `'0'`, not the value `0`.  In technical terms, the overload of `std::istream::operator>>` has this different behaviour when the right-hand argument has character type.

So input `0 0` on an ASCII system would generate output `48 * 12 + 48` which happens to be `624`.

You probably want to read into an int variable and then convert to the range of `k.p` (with some error handling in case of out-of-range input).

Comment: The debug output really confused me. If it were `0[Space]` I would have immediately spotted the mistake. So why is it `00` instead of `0[Space]`?

Comment: You are asking why `cout << k.p << k.o` outputs `00` and not `0 0`?  You didn't output a space at any stage...

Comment: No. Since I read two characters, why isn't the second a space (leaving the next character, another zero, in the stream) but the zero that should have been left?

Comment: @iBug istream `>>` skips whitespace (use `.get()` or `noskipws` manipulator to not do that)